# Using Regionerate 0.7.3.0 with Sharp Develop 4.4

Tags: c#, add-in, region, sharpdevelop

We use Regionerate at work with Visual Studio 2010 and it works great!

I would like to use it at home for my personal projects.  I use Sharp Develop 4.4.

I installed Regionerate 0.7.3.0 and added the plugin to Sharp Develop.  I can see new items in the menus (Regionerate this, Regionerate Settings, et al...).

When I try to select one of these items, I get an error message such as (sample shown is for Regionerate Settings, but Regionerate this produces a similar message...):

> Cannot find class:
>   Rauchy.Regionerate.Presentation.Addins.SharpDevelop.DocumentCommand
>   Future missing objects will not cause an error message.

I tried to search the web for an answer, but I'm out of luck...

What could cause this error?

How can I make Regionerate work in Sharp Develop?

Thank you for your help!

Ghis

Comment: Contact the developer of the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to make this work...

I had to:

- Retrieve the Regionerate source code
- Build it for .NET Framework 4.0 (same version used by SharpDevelop)
- Update the SharpDevelop referenced assemblies for the ones in version 4.4
- Adapt a few classes to make things work with SharpDevelop 4.4.

Actually, Regionerate 0.7.3.0 was designed for SharpDevelop 3.0, so a few things changed since then...

I will post a patch to the package maintainer so that everyone can benefit from it.

Ghis